# Path Mapping Module Resolution (Typescript 2.0)

Tags: typescript

i have a question about Path Mapping Module Resolution (Typescript 2.0).

I have a project with structure https://github.com/sanex3339/javascript-obfuscator/tree/strictNullChecks

My tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In file https://github.com/sanex3339/javascript-obfuscator/blob/dev/src/JavaScriptObfuscator.ts i set

```
import { INode } from 'interfaces/nodes/INode';
import { IObfuscator } from "interfaces/IObfuscator";
import { IOptions } from 'interfaces/IOptions';
import { IOptionsPreset } from "interfaces/IOptionsPreset";

import { JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI } from 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI';
import { Obfuscator } from 'Obfuscator';
import { Options } from 'Options';
```

All interfaces (.d.ts extension) will correctly imported without any errors, but on 3 last imports i get an error:

```
Can't resolve 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI' in '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src'
```

Why i got this error and why no error during interfaces imports?

Interesting, if i look at trace resolution log, i will see:

```
======== Resolving module 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI' from '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src/JavaScriptObfuscator.ts'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
'baseUrl' option is set to '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src', using this value to resolve non-relative module name 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI'
'paths' option is specified, looking for a pattern to match module name 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI'.
Module name 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI', matched pattern '*'.
Trying substitution '*', candidate module location: 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src/cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI'.
File '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src/cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src/cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI.ts', result '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src/cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI.ts'
======== Module name 'cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI' was successfully resolved to '/home/username/PhpstormProjects/javascript-obfuscator/src/cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI.ts'. ========
```

Comment: seems odd to me. What happens if you change import statement to: `import { JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI } from "./cli/JavaScriptObfuscatorCLI";`? Perhaps making it an explicitly relative path would fix it.

Comment: Currently all my imports is relative, and i want replace it with absolute imports with using of path mapping module resolution.

Yes, with relative imports everythink ok, but this is not what i want.

Comment: Like javascript, typescript doesn't support importing modules absolutely; it's just ES6 modules really. There's probably a special/legacy rule for importing type definitions for some reason.

I'm with you, it sucks.

Comment: look at this PR
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: Hi, it seems to me that your configuration of typescript is correct. I think, that problem is at module bundler, and you are using webpack for transpiling and publishing to dist. Webpack can have problem with resolving of non-relative modules as well, and of course webpack doesn't care about imports of types (typescript skips them). Could you check resolve.modulesDirectories and remove relative signs to resolve.modulesDirectories = ['src'] although i would suggest resolve.root, maybe this will help you...

Comment: all errors i get before bundling

Comment: and could you tell me how do you compile typescript? as project by typescript or by webpack analysis and tsloader? I thought that you use npm run build, if so webpack can have problem to locate next module for streaming into ts-loader. If i'm totaly wrong ignore me ;-) anyway nice project, i found few nice approaches inside, thanks for sharing...

Comment: Hi, did you figure out this problem? I have exactly the same problem with TS 2.0

Comment: i didn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is definitely not from typescript, but from webpack. Since you are using webpack 2.0 the relevant loader property you should set is the `modules:` property:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts'],
    modules: ['./src', './node_modules']
},
```

I cloned your project and set the `resolve` property to the above setup and was able to compile the project wihtout issues.